# "спустя время", "в один из дней" - это по-русски?

Tags: стилистика

Часто слышу от тележурналистов выражения "спустя время", "в один из дней"  в качестве обстоятельств времени. Мне кажется, это что-то диалектное, а может быть, уже общерусское?

Answer (score 2):

Это, конечно, нельзя назвать хорошим русским языком.

Comment: А поподробнее? С Софией мы, похоже, договорились: выражение «в один из дней» требует либо последующей («В один из дней, заполненных такими мыслями,»), либо предшествующей  конкретизации: «Уже неделю стояла… и в один из ЭТИХ дней». Сюда просится определенный артикль, а в «спустя время» - неопределенный  Потому и царапают мой слух  эти выражения,  что без артиклей они не имеют смысла. Ну как можно жить, действовать и не попасть при этом ни в один из дней! Все-таки наше время очень плотно на дни поделено, никаких дырок между ними нет.

Answer (score 1):

Такое выражение вполне оправдано. Такое выражение зафиксировано в словарях: Немного спустя, в зн. нареч. Разг.
Немного времени спустя = Немного времени спустя (Большой толковый словарь под редакцией Кузнецова).
"Спустя время" - немного погодя, позднее, затем, вскоре, впоследствии, после, по прошествии времени, спустя некоторое время. (Словарь синонимов, Тришин В.Н., 2010).

В один из дней тоже вполне допустимое выражение. Дней бывают много. "В один из дней"  - значит ***в какой-то один из многих дней.***

Comment: Выражения «Немного спустя» и «Немного времени спустя» вообще не имеют отношения к моему вопросу. Тот факт, что слово или выражение зафиксировано словарями, еще не делает его литературным. 
Разве словарь Тришина является нормативным? Я не заметила там стилистических помет (например: разговорное, диалектное, просторечное, площадная брань).
«Дней бывают много.» Логика - супер! Дней вообще много. Если бы автор конкретизировал, например: «В один из дней 1917 года», у меня не было бы возражений.

Answer (score 0):

Перед нами, надо надеяться, примеры хорошего русского языка. Заменить выражения "в один из дней" и "спустя время" синонимами как-то не получается, они имеют вполне определенное значение.

В ОДИН ИЗ ДНЕЙ

В один из дней мы узнали, что князь Ливен уволен по прошению от должности (В. П. Мещерский. Мои воспоминания (1897).

В один из дней, следовавших за этим разговором Лизы с Розановым, последний позвонил у подъезда очень парадного дома на невской набережной Васильевского острова (Н. С. Лесков, 1864).

В один из дней, заполненных такими мыслями, она рванула в аэропорт и перехватила самолет, идущий через Вашингтон из Женевы в Эл-Эй (В. Аксенов (2005).

Поверьте, что в один из дней вечной весны в парке Монсо среди розовых и белых цветущих каштанов, среди тюльпанов и роз вы наконец увидите свои изваяния, созданные из неслыханного материала (В. П. Катаев).

СПУСТЯ ВРЕМЯ

Годков пять поколобродит: апельсины, лимоны… а спустя время, смотришь, имение-то с аукциона продают (М.Е. Салтыков-Щедрин. Пошехонская старина).

Спустя время раскрасневшаяся Мавра, с платком, съехавшим набок, торочила на проулке бабьей толпе (М. А. Шолохов).

Спустя время Алексей выпрямился на козлах, прислушался, указал в темноту кнутовищем (А. Н. Толстой, 1928).

Comment: «Заменить выражения "в один из дней" и "спустя время" синонимами как-то не получается.» А у меня получается! В русском языке есть прекрасное слово «однажды». Разве "в один из дней" несет в себе больше смысла?Вместо "спустя время" можно сказать "некоторое время спустя" (здесь явно не хватает неопределенного артикля). Приведенные тексты М.Е. Салтыкова-Щедрина и М. А. Шолохова не могу принять за образец, поскольку они имеют вполне определенную стилистическую окраску.

Comment: Из 4-х примеров употребления выражения  «В ОДИН ИЗ ДНЕЙ» только первый имеет отношение к заданному мной вопросу. В остальных примерах это не самостоятельное обстоятельство времени, оно имеет последующую конкретизацию:
В один из дней, следовавших за этим разговором
В один из дней, заполненных такими мыслями,
в один из дней вечной весны
К авторам этих текстов у меня нет никаких претензий.

Comment: ОДНАЖДЫ, нареч. Самое близкое значение - как-то раз. О. заговорили о давно забытом событии.  О. мы все пили чай на террасе. Также добавим примеров для "в один из дней": В один из дней Андреев удивился, что он ещё живёт (В. Т. Шаламов). В один из дней стих ветер и наладилась погода во всех трех пунктах. И еще 202 вхождения в Нацкорпусе, к которым никто не предъявляет никаких претензий. Все дело в том, что для передачи именно этого значения нет точного синонима, "однажды" подходит далеко не всегда. Не думаю, что следует сужать лексику языка, исходя из неясных предположений о диалектности слова.

Comment: В телевизионных текстах этих вхождений намного больше. Я человек немолодой и помню времена, когда таких "вхождений" там не было вовсе. Наш язык за последние 25 лет очень изменился, и я склонна винить в этом СМИ. Я так и не поняла, почему "в один из дней": для вас то ли звучит информативнее, чем "однажды", то ли вообще несет другой смысл. Хотелось бы получить ответ профессионала. Ссылки на писателей, даже самых уважаемых, не решают вопрос. Написал же когда-то Лермонтов "Из пламя и света рожденное слово", это не значит, что нам всем следует склонять слово "пламя" именно так.

Comment: В Нацкорусе приводятся примеры из произведений классиков, из которых видно, что выражение " в один из дней" применялось еще в 19 веке, мне оно даже кажется немного архаичным. "Однажды" - это в один конкретный день, а "в один из дней" обозначает неопределенный период. Выражение это относится  в прозаической речи, это не "из пламя и света", думаю, что носители языка, а тем более известные писатели, различали эти варианты. Если Вас интересует мнение профессионалов, то лучше обратиться за консультацией, к примеру, в Грамоту.ру, а здесь работают преимущественно любители.

Comment: Извините, но я так и не поняла, что вы хотели сказать. Сначала вы пишете:
«ОДНАЖДЫ, нареч. Самое близкое значение - как-то раз», а потом: "Однажды" - это в один конкретный день. Если бы мне хотелось указать на «один конкретный день», я бы сказала «вчера», «неделю назад». «25 мая 1999 года», и т.п. Неужели "Однажды" звучит для вас определеннее, чем "в один из дней"? Профессионалы мы или нет, но мы носители русского языка, а значит можем найти общий язык и понять друг друга. Но мне вас пока понять не удается.

Comment: У меня есть знакомый, который не имеет никакого отношения к филологии, но при этом у него неплохое чувство языка. Давайте спросим его. - Есть разница между "однажды" и " в один из дней?  - Конечно, есть. В один из дней - это в какой-то день определенного периода времени, а однажды - просто в какой-то день. Но  в один из дней - это книжное выражение.

Comment: Да, пожалуй, разница в стиле есть. К примеру, мы описываем время: Уже неделю стояла солнечная морозная погода, и в один из дней мы решили прогуляться по зимнему лесу. Здесь "однажды" подходит меньше, чем " в один из дней".